# Clicking Details in Result Window in Geoportal Modifies Address to Local IP

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoportal

I'm using ESRI's Geoportal Extension 10.0. The issue I'm having is when the preview or details is selected in the results window after a search the outside web address is reverted back to the local IP address. The metadata and open options don't change the outside web address to the local IP. Any ideas? I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Three photos are attached. The first screenshot is the options to click on after a search result. The second is the outside web address after a search. The third is what happens when clicking on details or preview.

[image: search result window]

[image: outside web address]

[image: Inside IP Address after clicking Details]

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this?  If so, would you be able to self-Answer, or alternatively revise your question provide an update such as whether you are still striking it at ArcGIS 10.2?